# Django-PuSH package not working

Tags: python, django, websub

I wrote a simple django project that subscribes my blog using pubsubhubbub and streams latest articles.. I used django-push package to do it

How ever, its not working and neither showing error. So, can anyone help me on it?

Here is the Project: http://dpaste.com/805590/

I am using http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/ as Hub Server (supported by blog - Google's Blogger)

Comment: Maybe you should give a shot at another public hub, like http://pubsubhubbub.superfeedr.com ?

Comment: @JulienGenestoux I am using blogspot.com and it supports the above mentioned... I don't think it can be done using superfeedr.com

Comment: HA, sorry, I misunderstood the question. So, you're basically not getting notifications when you update your blog? It's probably best to ask on the PubSubHubbub group : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pubsubhubbub